# how to hide text behind embedded Flash SWF object in HTML

Tags: html, text, hidden, swfobject, embedded-flashplayer

I am trying display customized text behind my embedded Flash swf file on HTML. I embed using SWFObject.

The purpose is to show the custom text whenever Flash player is not installed. 
This might also help with the flash illiterate web-crawlers.

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SWFObject already gives you the option to show alternative content when Flash is not installed.

http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/wiki/documentation

Look for the section **"STEP 1: Embed both Flash content and alternative content using standards compliant markup"**